# DNS host record problem while use with Active directory

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

i describe briefly what i do. i take an internet domain name like abc.com and create a server with active directory to host this domain name. i have 4 servers main server which host AD also work as web server and other 3 servers which are member of AD handling different roles of Exchange for mailing service. we have 8 public ip address on each server.

Now the problem is this when we go to the dns zone of the abc.com it reflect 32 public ip address as the host ip or you called A records due to ad integration in dns zone. I need just three public ip as host record to run the website in the DNS zone of the website .

Kindly suggest any way to control the dns entries while AD integration.

Comment: First, clarification is needed on the question. What are you asking?

Next, are you Nat'ing? Are you running DHCP? 

Why are you limited to three addresses? Are those your publics?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to determine what you are asking, but it sounds like you confusing your Internal naming and IP addressing with your external addressing.

All of your machines are on your AD domain by the sounds of it. Therefore they will be using your internal DNS servers and may be getting their IP addresses from your DHCP server, most likely internal IP addresses (or they should be).

Your web server will then also have external IP's setup to allow access to only the web server from the internet.

I hope this helps make things a little clearer. If you can clarify the issues you are having, then I can expand further.